# How can we join multiple files in which each file the first column is the same but the results are different in the second column?

Tags: csv, unix, join, paste

We have already tried the command join but it hasn´t worked.

file1.csv:

```
2013   25                
2014   62
2015   26
```

file2.csv:

```
2013 65
2014 52
2015 1
```

And what we want is:
output.csv

```
2013 25 65
2014 62 52
2015 25 1
```

Comment: is your question related to any particular programming language? please specify it in your question.

Comment: We have to use unix language program in linux.

Comment: I can not post a solution now, but I would choose sed and bash for this.

Comment: `man join`: `join - join lines of two files on a common field` - - `join [OPTION]... FILE1 FILE2` - - `The default join field is the first, delimited by blanks.`

Comment: There are a number of open-source toolkits that support the type of join you want. A good list is at https://github.com/dbohdan/structured-text-tools#other-tools.

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
cut -f2 file2.csv > temp
paste file1.csv temp > output
rm temp;
```

hope this will help